# What shape does this 3D graph form?

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus, euclidean-geometry

What shape does the graph of $x^2 + y^2 = z^4$ equal? The graph is 3D, with x,y,z axis.

Particularly, what shape does it form when z is under the restriction $0<= z <= 1$

I know that $x^2 + y^2 = z^2$ gives a cone shape, and that makes sense and is easy to imagine in my head. (There are increasingly smaller/bigger circles stacked ontop of eachother for each z value)

However, I can't seem to figure out what this graph means. Is it taking the area of a cone and using that as the side of a square?

Thank you for the help in advance!

Comment: @Moo do I need calculus to find the area of this? Or can I do it geometrically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The horizontal slices (fixed $z$) of $x^2+y^2=z^4$ i.e. $r=z^2$ are similar to those of $x^2+y^2=z^2$ i.e. $r = z$ ($z\in[0,1]$ is given). If $z=z_0$ then in $r = z_0^2$  describes a circle of radius $z_0^2$. So the only difference is in how the radius changes as you vary $z$.

The difference is that when $z<1$, the circles will be smaller than those for the cone, and when $z>1$, the circles will be larger. At exactly $z=1$ the two surfaces have the same slice ($r=1$).

Here is a plot in $r$-$z$ space of $r=z$ and $r=z^2$ (ignore the bottom half of the graph):
[image]

If we rotate the red curve around the $z$-axis, we [get the 3D plot](https://www.math3d.org/B6EPJxGfS) of your surface (again, ignore the bottom half):
[image]

As for the area, this is a surface of revolution; generally, if we are rotating $r=f(z)$ on $z\in[a,b]$ around the $z$ axis then the surface area is
$$ A = 2\pi \int_a^b f(z) \sqrt{1+ f'(z)^2}dz $$
An explanation for this formula can be found [here](https://courses.lumenlearning.com/calculus2/chapter/area-of-a-surface-of-revolution/) (found on google). In our specific case, this is
$$A = 2\pi \int_0^1 z^2 \sqrt{1+4z^2} dz =  \dfrac{18\sqrt{5} - \operatorname{arsinh}2}{32}\pi.$$

Comment: Thank you so much! Could you tell me how I would go about finding the area of this shape? (Preferably without calculus, but if that is the only way I understand). Also, my understanding of this explanation is that it differs from the cone in the sense that the cones radius has now become radius squared? But if that is the case wouldn't the cone's radius just become $(1^2)^2$ ?

Comment: Oh, yes, the radius of the base is still 1. I didn't notice that there was the restriction $z\le 1$, sorry. I've added something for the area @TizzleRizzle

Comment: Do you know any way to solve this geometrically? I know the calculus and understand it but a geometric solution would be really cool too.

Comment: @TizzleRizzle I find it hard to believe a geometric solution can lead to a constant involving $\operatorname{arcsinh} 2$. But if you find one please share with me.